# Create table with PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute()

My code:

```
<?php
session_start();
require("../connecting-to-database.php");

$query = "CREATE TABLE `classes`(
                       `ID_class` int(11),
                       `name` varchar(255),
                       PRIMARY KEY(`ID_class`))";
$pdo->execute($query);
```

What is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

`Execute` is for prepared statements not executing directly.
Also don't forget to catch your exception.

Try the following:

```
<?php
session_start();
require("../connecting-to-database.php");


try {
$query = $pdo->prepare("CREATE TABLE `classes`(
                   `ID_class` int(11),
                   `name` varchar(255),
                   PRIMARY KEY(`ID_class`))");
$query->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: I have this and I also get the same error: `<?php
 session_start();
 require("../connecting-to-database.php");

 $query = $pdo->prepare("CREATE TABLE `classes`(
                     `ID_class` int(11),
                        `name` varchar(255),
                        PRIMARY KEY(`ID_class`))");
 $pdo->execute($query);`

Comment: I was missing a close parenthesis. Try it now.

Comment: I knew it. Still the same problem. The code, which I use is up.

Comment: You still need the `prepare()`

Comment: Yeah- I’m answering on my phone while getting my kids ready to leave the house. Sorry about that. Try it now.

Comment: Fixed missing quote- try it now J.Doe